# Level shifting with BSS138 - weird values

Tags: mosfet, i2c, level-shifting, 3.3v

I need to connect 5V and 3.3V devices via I2C as follows:

[image]

I've connected 3.3V and 5V pull-ups and tried to measure the voltage. There is 5V on HV and TX_HV but 4,7V on LV / TX_LV.

Putting TX to LOW generates LOW on the other side, but I have a problem with 3.3V - I see cca 4.7V.

My PCB:

[image]

Comment: FET mounted backwards? Does the 4.7V disappear if you remove the 5V? Where does the 3V3 come from?

Comment: Do you have a picture of your setup?

Comment: LV and HV is connected to regulated 3.3V / 5.0V - arduino uno. 4.7 disapear if I remove 5V - then there is 3.3V

Comment: Wouter means to ask if you accidentally swapped source and drain. Source should go at the 3V3 side and drain at the 5V side.

Comment: http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/interface/pdf/an97055.pdf paragraph 2.3 gives a nice explanation on how a MOSFET level shifter works.

Comment: My PCB : http://admin.dtech.sk/PCB.jpg

Comment: In PCB picture - there is also MOSFET orientation - as I know, the orientation is correct - alone pin is D, then G, S are "under"

Comment: So, I think orientation is correct - how can I measure if MOSFET is dead ?

Comment: You can try and measure the intrinsic source-drain body diode and capacitance from gate-to-source (take the MOSFET off the PCB first).

Comment: My measurements:<br>

Comment: G->S , S->G [ cca 155 ohm ] ;  S->D 460ohm ; D->S closed - seems that diode is ok ; G->D 555ohm ; D->G closed;   Capacitance I don't know yet [ don't have multimeter and for now don't want to create RC ]

Comment: 90% I think first time I was able to measure 3.3V but then only 4.7V. I thought that it was just multimeter , but now I think that MOSFET dies - but how? What I did : First I connected VL [3.3V] and VH [ 5`V] - power source was already switched ON - so is it possible to destroy MOSFET that way ?  - first connecting VH, then VL [ or VL then VH ] ?

Comment: I've replaced BSS138 with 2N7002 - and it works - could you pls say that 2N7002 is for this purpose OK and not running on the "edge"... than

Comment: With 10k pull-ups, current can't exceed 0,5mA [ 5V], and max. drain current is cca 115mA. So I think that for this purpose [ only signal driving ] this is a good choice ...

Comment: Vgs of BSS138 must to be at least 2V, so, isn't good...